# Is there a ggplot2 function that can plot the straight line inferred from a linear model that came from a call to lm()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

With base R's plotting, I can generate a plot of a new linear model that I just generated with `lm` very quickly:

```
with(mtcars,{
  plot(wt,mpg)
  abline(lm(mpg~wt))})
```

Is there a ggplot2 equivalent? I tried `geom_abline` but nothing that I've seen suggests that it works on forumla objects.

To be clear, I do not want to have to extract the coefficients from the linear model and pass them to `ggplot`. I also do not want to generate the linear model with a `ggplot2` function. I want exactly what base R has - the ability to pass linear model objects to a plotting function in a way that displays its corresponding straight line.

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/insert-regression-model-into-ggplot2/2439/7 suggests not (the new analog to `fortify` would be `geom_line(data=broom::augment(fitted_model), aes(y=.fitted))`

Comment: Seeing how he strictly forbad fetching coefficients, I wouldn't be surprised if he also frowns upon fetching fitted values.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for that, I'll definitely look at `?fortify`, although it's alarming to see that it may be depreciated and therefore suggests something similar to what you've offered. Truth be told, I'm most happy to see that I made the same plot as the link's example, but with fewer lines!

Comment: He fetches the fitted values from the lm object and plots those. That's just a hop, skip and a stone's throw away from fethcing the _coefficients_ and plotting those instead. You're essentially digging into the lm object to fetch parts of it that you can fit to existing geom functions that otherwise wouldn't take the lm object.

Comment: yup. Also, `broom::augment` is generally seen as the replacement for `fortify`

Comment: It might be interesting and helpful to have a little bit more context for **why** you don't want to do the things you ruled out. For avoiding `geom_smooth`, I can imagine you might already have fitted the model and don't want to re-fit it. It's harder to understand why you don't want to extract the coefficients.  Is brevity your primary goal? What's your use case?

Comment: I've certainly been in situations where I have wanted to just smack in the fitted line of a model at hand, _without having to think_. @J.Mini you should write the function to do this and ask if anyone wants it in their package, and if not release one yourself. I'd happily give it a download the first week :)

Comment: @BenBolker Honestly, it was just "hey, base R uses a cool to trick to do this really easily. Maybe, ggplot can do the same trick?".

Comment: base R isn't all that cool. `abline` doesn't handle one of the axis being log transformed for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're allowed to do stuff but just not the stuff you listed, then I'd go with `stat_function`:

```r
m <- lm( mpg~wt, data=mtcars )

ggplot( mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg) ) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_function( fun=function(x)predict(m, newdata=data.frame(wt=x)), color="red" )
```

[image]

Comment: Dammit, this technically doesn't violate any of the restrictions that I listed.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_abline(data = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars) %>% broom::tidy(), 
              aes(intercept = estimate[1], slope = estimate[2]))
```

or:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_abline(data = coef(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)) %>% t() %>% data.frame(), 
              aes(intercept = X.Intercept., slope = wt))
```

Comment: These both violate "_I do not want to have to extract the coefficients from the linear model and pass them to ggplot_".

Answer (score 0):

The function `geom_smooth` can do something similar to what you're saying, although I don't think you can pass the object directly inside there:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(wt, mpg))
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I ruled out: "_I also do not want to generate the linear model with a ggplot2 function_".